# How react update specific state inner state object?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

In this example below:

```
  const [course, setCourse] = useState({
    id: null,
    slug: "",
    title: "",
    authorId: null,
    category: "",
  });
  function handleTitleChange(e) {
    setCourse({
      ...course,
      title: e.target.value,
    });
  }
```

How React know to update `title` state value, and don't touch other?

If I make copy from the state in `course` why is here no error?
 `course.title` exist or not? And how I update him only post bellow his name?

Is this a React system or a JavaScript system?

Thanks!

Comment: For performance, the spread operator is always the better solution, see https://medium.com/@verdi/avoid-object-mutation-in-react-for-better-performance-4cf17b13e1e8

Comment: @keikai, yes, thanks.